# How to calculate KB/second for n number of users using Average bytes and average response time as per jtl file generated via non gui mode script run

Tags: jmeter

When a script is run for 2 virtual users in non gui mode.how to calculate KB/sec using average bytes and elapsed time populated in Jtl file.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s find how to calculate the Throughput :

```
Throughput = 1/[Total Time]

Where Total time = [Avg bites] * [1/(KB/Sec)]

Where using [1/(KB/Sec)] we are getting the Time consumed in Sec. For 1 KB of data .

Then simply for one sample i.e Avg bites of that sample = [Avg bites] * [1/(KB/Sec)]

So Throughput is for one sample = 1/[{Avg bites} * {1/(KB/Sec)}]

Eg :

Throughput = 1/[Total Time]

Total time = (6.041 KB) * [1/90] =0.0671 sec [Say , Avg Bytes=6.041 kb & kb/sec=90 ]

Then Throughput = 1/ 0.0671 = 14.9031297/Sec
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .This calculation worked for single user . But results are not matching for 2 users .For example :   Min -2036 , Max -4424  , Average response time - 3097 ms , Standard Dev -992.79 , Average bytes 23581 Number of users 3 Here using above formula KB/sec=     7.43Kb/sec whereas if I open Jtl file in j meter summary report listner it has value -15.62 Kb/sec                                                                                                                 . Due to this reason throughput is not matching with jmeter summary result value.